# woo commerce Add to cart not working If quantity Exceeds than stock

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I am facing a Woocommerce in stock quantity validation issue when I add qty more than in stock quantity I am getting error:

[image]

I have tried this code:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {
    // do your validation, if not met switch $passed to false
    if ( 1 != 2 ){
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You can not do that', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

My web site [live link](http://worldmatrix.co.in/empire/product/ram-bandhu-chivada-masala)

The issue: Add to cart "infinite spinning icon" so not adding to cart.

How this can be solved?

Comment: Add to cart loading not adding cart my website URL is: http://www.worldmatrix.co.in/empire/product/ram-bandhu-chivada-masala/

Comment: Is this happening with this custom code or without it? You should try to better explain what you are trying to do with this code **editing your question**. Thanks

Comment: @AnsarulHaque This issue doesn't seems to be happening any more. I tested on your site and add_to_cart is going through.

Comment: yes @Dhaval I have resolved with using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-minimum-maximum-quantity/

Comment: @AnsarulHaque you could have used [backorder allowed](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-23) function to allow purchases of more than stocked quantity. This is core feature and you don&#39;t need any plugin for that.